# OpenERP - selecting Create dropdown box option does not launch the dialog window

Tags: odoo

I have a dropdown box for Class ID in a custom view. When I type new, non existent classID in the dropdown box, the dropdown shows options, one of which is Create new_class _id. However, when I click on Create '0078' for instance, no dialog window is launched and the new class is created. I don't know 100% if this is correct behaviour. Please see the picture. What I have to do to launch the window?

[image]

Comment: can you post your code.....  ;)

Comment: I don't know where to find the code. That's the part of the puzzle!

Comment: That will be created automatically , when you click on the `Create "0078"` .....   after click on that go to the button besides the **Item Class** field  (that logo shows with arrow sign).... that will show you your created item and dialog window...  :)

Comment: Thank you. So I assume that's the correct behaviour then.

Answer (score 0):

That will be created automatically , when you click on the Create "0078" ..... after click on that go to the button besides the Item Class field (that logo shows with arrow sign).... that will show you your created item and dialog window... :)

It will be true when there are no required field in the window that will be open for create new item. If you put more than one required field in dialog-box(form view), then it will pop-up. that you are asking.....!!

–  Mischievous